# Java - Android Mobile Vision face detection with contours

Tags: java, android, face-detection, vision

I am experimenting with the face detection of the Mobile Vision API. I am trying to get the facial landmarks' contours. But on building the FaceDetector it is giving me this exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.camera2tut, PID: 27106
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid build options
```

And the FaceDetector is telling me that "Contour is not supported for non-SELFIE mode." Here is my code for setting up the FaceDetector:

```
import com.google.android.gms.vision.face.FaceDetector;
[...]
mFaceDetector = new FaceDetector.Builder(this)
            .setTrackingEnabled(true)
            .setMinFaceSize((float)0.4)
            .setLandmarkType(FaceDetector.CONTOUR_LANDMARKS)
            .setClassificationType(FaceDetector.NO_CLASSIFICATIONS)
            .setProminentFaceOnly(true)
            .setMode(FaceDetector.ACCURATE_MODE)
            .build();
```

For the FaceDetector.Builder there is no option for setting a "selfie mode":
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/face/FaceDetector.Builder

Althouth the FaceDetector has a constant SELFIE_MODE:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/face/FaceDetector

From the description of this constant, it seems that `.setProminentFaceOnly(true)` comes closest to the selfie mode, but it does not seem to enable it.

If I just detect the landmarks with `.setLandmarkType(FaceDetector.ALL_LANDMARKS)`, the detector can be build. But how do I use this ominous "selfie" mode, how do I get the contours?

Comment: Did you manage to get face contours to work?

Comment: Not yet, see below.

Comment: It is working Now . check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
.setMode(FaceDetector.SELFIE_MODE)
```

Comment: I have tried this with a configuration similar to the above. However, I still get no contours out of the face detector. If you take a look at the documentation for  FaceDetector.Builder setMode it doesn't actually say you can use SELFIE_MODE. https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/face/FaceDetector.Builder.html#setMode(int)

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to this, @hsienting! It does not seem to be in the documentation and for some reason I overlooked it working with Android Studio. However, it is still not working. I am using these two options now:

'.setLandmarkType(FaceDetector.CONTOUR_LANDMARKS)', 
'.setMode(FaceDetector.SELFIE_MODE)', 

and I disabled classifications as contours apparently don't work together with them, but my List of contours is empty. I can initialize the face detector now, but this does give me nothing: 

'List<Contour> faceContours = face.getContours();'

Comment: Did anyone else notice an update? I am using '...gms:play-services-vision:17.0.2'. The face area is a square now (vs. rectangle). I seemingly can force this change on other devices by actively searching for updates in the Play store.

I also seem not to be able to use the face tracker withing two activities of the same app, i.e. initialize the face tracker, release it on activity pause, and re-initialize it in another activity I am switching to. I don't get an error, but it won't detect any faces anymore in a second activity. I would really need this option for my current project.

Answer (score 0):

Create your Detector like this:

```
new FaceDetector.Builder(ctx).setTrackingEnabled(true) //can be false too
.setLandmarkType(FaceDetector.CONTOUR_LANDMARKS)
.setMode(FaceDetector.SELFIE_MODE)
.setProminentFaceOnly(true)
.build();
```

Do let me know if full code is required to capture the contour points.

my gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.0.3'
```